# App Subtitle is not visible in app store other than default language

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded an app on Store with subtitle.

The app default language is English(U.S.).

When I view the app on the App Store with phone language English(U.S.) subtitle is visible.

But when I view the app on App Store with phone language German subtitle is not visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appstore support questions are off-topic

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but you can check this option in app store connect.
Add new locale using + button. refer attached image.

[image]

Comment: Hello

Thanks for the reply.

But I need an exact answer Because I have to share the same with the client.

Please share any link where you find the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app store language with your phone language is the same:

[image: App Store Language]